# Combine two objects with a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I need to combine two objects based on a particular value.

```
let rc = {"__type__":"o","L5L6":"NA","L1":"NA","L2":"X","L3":"NA","L4":"X","L5":"X","L6":"NA","L3L4":"AND"}
let pp= {"__type__":"o","L5L6":"NA","L1":"X","L2":"X","L3":"NA","L4":"NA","L5":"NA","L6":"NA","L3L4":"NA"}
```

I tried using

```
 merged = {...rc,...pp}
```

but it combines based on the order you combine so NA in pp prefers over rc,but I need to combine two arrays based on the value 'X'.

**Output Array**

```
Rc has L2,L4,L5 as X and L3L4 as AND ( can be OR)
pp has L1,L2 as X
```

so the output should be

```
[
   levels:    [L1,L2,L4,L5],
   relations: [{L3L4:AND}]
  ]
```

Comment: "based on the value 'X'" meaning on any given property, or you want to combine all the properties with a value of "X"? Please provide an example of what the result would look like.

Comment: update  the question

Comment: @jonrsharpe : It is just merging but i need to merge based on the value 'X'

Comment: `Object.assign(...Object.keys(rc).map(key => ({[`${key}`]: rc[key] === "NA" ? pp[key] : rc[key] }) ))`